# Delphi Clipboard: Read file properties of a file copied

Tags: delphi, clipboard, filesize, delphi-10-seattle

I would like to retrieve the file size of a file copied into the clipboard.

I read the [documentation of TClipboard](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/Vcl.Clipbrd.TClipboard) but I did not find a solution.

I see that `TClipboard.GetAsHandle` could be of some help but I was not able to complete the task.

Comment: You can read this articles: [article 1](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/win32/shell/clipboard?redirectedfrom=MSDN) and [article 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dataxchg/clipboard). VCL's docs on `TClipboard` not very useful in your case.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Could you please give me an example on how to match MS docs with VCL ones?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just from inspecting the clipboard I could see at least 2 useful formats:

`FileName` (Ansi) and `FileNameW` (Unicode) which hold the file name copied to the clipboard. 
So basically you could register one of then (or both) with `RegisterClipboardFormat` and then retrieve the information you need. e.g.

```
uses Clipbrd;

var
  CF_FILE: UINT;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  CF_FILE := RegisterClipboardFormat('FileName');
end;

function ClipboardGetAsFile: string;
var
  Data: THandle;
begin
  Clipboard.Open;
  Data := GetClipboardData(CF_FILE);
  try
    if Data <> 0 then
      Result := PChar(GlobalLock(Data)) else
      Result := '';
  finally
    if Data <> 0 then GlobalUnlock(Data);
    Clipboard.Close;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Clipboard.HasFormat(CF_FILE) then
    ShowMessage(ClipboardGetAsFile);
end;
```

Once you have the file name, just get it's size or other properties you want.
Note: The above was tested in Delphi 7. for Unicode versions of Delphi use the `FileNameW` format.

An alternative and more practical way (also useful for multiple files copied) is to register and handle the [`CF_HDROP`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/clipboard#cf_hdrop) format.

Here is an example in Delphi: [How to paste files from Windows Explorer into your application](http://delphidabbler.com/tips/161)

Comment: Thanks for the sample, i tried it but if i have a file in the clipboard i get [Content]
㩄瑜浥屰敖敮潴瀮杮꬀ꮫꮫꮫﺫﻮﻮ

Comment: I tried registering FileNameW and that one gives me the correct path to the copied file

Comment: @LaBracca, That was because you have Unicode Delphi version and I tested in Delphi 7 (Ansi, Non-Unicode). so in order to use the `FileName` format you need to replace `PChar` -> `PAnsiChar` and `string` -> `AnsiString`. In any case using `FileNameW` makes much more sense in a Unicode version/environment. With all that said I would personally go for the `CF_HDROP` since it can also process multiple files and you can't assume that a user only copied a single file. (`FileNameW` format will return the first one in the list in that case)